# Pulling data, mainly text from websites

Tags: vb.net

I'm fairly new to programming in general but I have delved into vb.net recently. I was looking into how to grab data from a website but don't fully comprehend how to or through what means.

My main end game is to just pull data for a lack of better word. Say for instance, a website shows text, I'd like to be able to pull that text into my program using vb.net. Is that possible?

I don't know how to use javascript, php and know only little of html/css. I'm of course willing to learn but I haven't had much luck searching for this specific information or solution. Without access to the websites database, is there another way for my app to read the website for what it would be displaying and retrieve this information? I'm mainly concerned with text, no other information is really needed. From what i've gathered, the information is tagged by something like an ID, or class? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Web servers essentially have 2 operations, POST, which is you sending something to the website, and GET, which is you requesting something from the website.

For the most part you can just do a GET of some sort on the website and it'll return what you request in a data format, likely JSON. You can often look for fields based on CSS selectors in the web page itself. Though, there are other ways and some HTTP libraries may return the data to you in various formats, mainly JSON and XML.

I'd suggest right click->view source on a web page to learn more about how they're structured. As for how to do a GET in javascript on some website, this code would grab the website at the URL you give it.

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); //the get request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText; //the website data in XML format.
}
```

Comment: That's good information. Thank you so far! Now, would any of this change if the website was built off a SQL server and it's utilizing Microsoft CRM. Originally, I built a connection in Excel to grab data from the database but I do not have the database for the new CRM information. That and i'm not using Excel anymore.

I won't be able to look at the source of the site for a couple of days but I wanted to gather as much information as I could before proceeding. I'll give the above code a try once I am able to and see what happens. Thanks again!

Comment: Websites have webpages composed of many GETs. You need to research a bit more on your own, these questions are much too general.

Comment: Ok, i've gathered a lot more information on what i'm attempting to do. *This is all just fun and hobby work*.

I'm trying to retrieve data from bungie.net using their API. I've succesfully pulled information from the site. It's pulled into the format JSON. I've gotten output for the JSON and managed to deserialize it. Problem is, i'm struggling to convert the information to be usable in my application. I have the JSON and my code i'm interested in if I need to post it. 

JSON code: http://pastebin.com/FMAW4Tbn
VB.NET: http://pastebin.com/uVXvxvwU